# Converses of transitivity

Tags: logic, relations, order-theory

Let $\prec$ be a binary relation. Two logically-equivalent ways to express transitivity are
\begin{align}
& a \prec b \to \forall x (x \prec a \to x \prec b) \\
& a \prec b \to \forall x (b \prec x \to a \prec x)
\end{align}
They have two distinct converses: [1]
\begin{align}
& \forall x (x \prec a \to x \prec b) \to a \prec b & \text{A} \\
& \forall x (b \prec x \to a \prec x) \to a \prec b & \text{B}
\end{align}

The only reference I've found to them is [2], which calls them "converse transitivity from below" and "converse transitivity from above", adding:

> Converse transitivity from below and converse transitivity from above are not necessarily the same, as the spouse/sibling example shows, and it is possible to construct other examples in which one or the other or both conditions do not hold.

My questions are the following:

1. Do properties A and B have other names in the literature?
2. Are they discussed in greater detail elsewhere in the literature?
3. Is there a name for a binary relation that satisfies transitivity and both of its converses?
4. What are some common, general mathematical structures that satisfy the above?

---

1. Note that both imply reflexivity.
2. John Randolph Lucas. §9.9 Converse Transitivity. *Conceptual Roots of Mathematics*. Routledge, 2002-09-11. Pages [253](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Q42EAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA253)-[254](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Q42EAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA254).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of these converses are in fact just equivalent to reflexivity.  You have already observed that they imply reflexivity, since the hypothesis of either converse is always true if $a=b$.  Conversely, suppose $\prec$ is reflexive and for all $x$, $x\prec a$ implies $x\prec b$.  In particular, we know that $a\prec a$ by reflexivity, and therefore $a\prec b$.  The other converse works similarly.

Comment: How can both of them be equivalent to reflexivity if they're not equivalent to each other? (I added a quote from the reference to the question.)

Comment: Either the reference is just wrong, or you are misunderstanding what it is saying.

Comment: I would guess the reference is actually talking about a restricted version of the converses you wrote in which the implication is only required to hold for $a\neq b$.

Comment: I see. So the answer to 3 is just "preorder"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.